# Can't access docker container over public ip

Tags: docker, docker-compose

So I am creating an application that is running in a docker container on port 3000 of my local machine. I can open the app at localhost:3000, I can also open it on another device but on the same network by using 192.168.68.100:3000. However, I can't access the app by visiting my_public_ip:3000. I added port forwarding on my router for port 3000. I am running the app using docker-compose up and this is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  main:
    container_name: main
    build:
      context: .
      target: development
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    command: npm run start:dev
    env_file:
      - .env
    networks:
      - webnet
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    container_name: db
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "..."
      MYSQL_USER: "..."
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "..."
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "..."
  adminer:
    container_name: adminer
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
networks:
  webnet:
```

Any suggestions what am I missing?

Comment: Try something like following in your dockercompose file: ports: 127.0.0.1:3000:3000

Comment: Thank you, but this didn't work. I would assume it had to be set to something like 0.0.0.0:3000:3000 but this doesn't work as well.

Comment: It sounds like the issue isn't with your Docker container or docker-compose file as you can connect to your application on your local network. I'd be looking at your ISP or your router as the culprit. Many ISPs don't allow incoming access or firewall certain ports. They could be using CGNAT. You might have different success connecting to your public_ip:3000 from outside your network or inside your network. You could try forwarding a different external port.